# Problem with encoding exporting a CSV file

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, csv, encoding

I'm using Asp.net mvc to generate a CSV file, but I'm having problems with special characters in portuguese language. I'm using the following code to return the file:

```
public FileContentResult RelMatriculas(RelRematriculaVM model)
{
    string fileContent = GenerateTheFile();
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(fileContent), "text/csv", "RelMatriculas.csv");
}
```

I'm setting utf8 as the encoding, but when a save the file and try to open it in Excel, I see junk characters instead of the special ones.

If I just open the file in notepad and save it, then open it again on excel, is show the characters correctly. Am I missing something to output the file as UTF8?

Comment: Using encoding with BOM might help: `new UTF8Encoding(true)`, or just `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898462/exporting-data-to-csv-from-controller

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is Excel expects BOM. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414118/5762332):

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
return File(result, "text/csv", "RelMatriculas.csv");
```