# Encoding of character in textfield doesnt show correctly in export using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, csv, character-encoding, export-to-csv

Someone put in this apostrophe when typing a height, probably a copy and paste from say a Word document.  It displays fine on the web but when doing an export the text reads with a funny character.  Is there something I can do either on the input save or export to fix this problem without causing issues through out the site?  I am using ASP.NET MVC and .NET 4.8.

Text Input

```
6’2
```

CSV Export

```
6â€™2
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/55247163/177416

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you save the file, the easiest might be to ensure it's written out as Unicode. Assuming you can opt for `StreamWriter`, you could do something like so:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Columns.Add("C1");
    dt.Columns.Add("C2");
    
    var r = dt.NewRow();
    r[0] = "test";
    r[1] = "6’2";
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
    
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.csv"); // defaults to Unicode
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            streamWriter.Write(row[i].ToString());
            streamWriter.Write(",");
        }
    streamWriter.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text seems to written out as Unicode (specifically UTF8) just fine.

Remember that a CSV file is nothing but bytes, so reading it correctly requires writer and reader to agree on encoding.

If you put a UTF8-encoded character [(U+2019)](https://unicode-table.com/en/2019/) the *reader* must also understand the same encoding, and agree to use it. If not, you will get "mojibake". This doesn't mean the content is wrong (or changed). It's just encoded in a format your reader does not expect.

Obviously you are using a western character set. If your computer was set to, say, Russian, your output would be different.

Can you reveal what you use to read the file created ? Maybe you should put BOM marks as suggested in a comment above ? This tells readers that do understand UTF8 that this *is* in fact a UTF8 file. Note: Readers that don't understand BOM marks may display these as unreadable characters.

If you **have** to use a legacy reader for this file, one solution may be to parse the file with [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) or similar tool.

```
    ’
    https://unicode-table.com/en/2019/
    
    UTF8 encoded:
        E2 80 99        hex
        226 128 153     decimal
    
    Read as Windows 1252
        6â€™2
    
      â = E2
      € = 80
      ™ = 99
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```cs
string utf8_String = "dayâ€™s";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(utf8_String);
utf8_String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```